# How do I get img src?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm not sure why, but I'm having trouble getting image src value?
Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="gallery">
 <img src="css/images/cat.jpg" id="main-img">
</div>
```

Here's my javascript:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    var currentImage = $("#main-img").attr("src");
    window.alert(currentImage);
}, 5000);
```

But I keep getting `undefined` whenever the alert comes up.

Comment: Check your console for errors. What you have works absolutely fine, assuming you've setup jQuery correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/pq07duv3/

Comment: Do you load jquery.js in your html page??

Comment: run it after page is loaded

Comment: @FastSnail it is, 5 seconds after in fact

Comment: but still page can take more than 5 seconds

Comment: `But I keep getting undefined whenever the alert comes up` Are you sure you don't get any other element with same ID?

Comment: Is there something else on the page with the id "main-image"?

Comment: Your code should work, so most likely you have another problem (look at some of the comments). See this plnkr (which is your code working) http://plnkr.co/edit/cMqiatQdGQD3ZE2vkvaD?p=preview

Comment: Yeah, it started working all of a sudden(without me changing any code), It might've been something wrong with my server.. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Just as a footnote as much as anything else.

For this `jQuery`:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var currentImage = $("#main-img").attr("src");
    window.alert(currentImage);
}, 5000);
```

the equivalent in vanilla `javascript` is:

```
setInterval(function(){
    var currentImage = document.querySelector('#main-img').getAttribute('src');
    window.alert(currentImage);
}, 5000);
```